# OpenVPN route issue

Tags: openvpn

I finally got OpenVPN to allow the server to communicate with the clients. The problem is that the clients can't respond to requests from the server. When I run

```
sudo tcpdump -i tun0
```

on the client, and ping it, I get

```
20:11:39.215473 IP gateblogs.com > 10.10.0.2: ICMP echo request, id 8489, seq 83, length 64
```

but the ping requests aren't answered. I also can't access the website hosted on it from the server, but other clients can. My server OpenVPN config is:

```
port 1194
proto tcp
dev tun0
sndbuf 0
rcvbuf 0
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key
dh dh.pem
topology subnet
server 10.10.0.0 255.255.255.0
route 10.10.0.0 255.255.255.0
push "iroute 10.10.0.0 255.255.255.0"
push "route 10.10.0.0 255.255.255.0"
cipher AES-256-GCM
auth SHA512
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
tls-cipher TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-256-GCM-SHA384
reneg-bytes 32000000
compress lz4-v2
push "compress lz4-v2"
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.222.222"
push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.220.220"
keepalive 10 120
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
verb 3
crl-verify /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki/crl.pem
duplicate-cn
client-to-client
topology subnet
log-append /var/log/openvpn.log
```

`tcpudump -i tun0` on the client during ping from server:

```
19:56:48.834510 IP gateblogs.com > 10.10.0.2: ICMP echo request, id 3878, seq 3, length 64
```

it seems to be getting the external IP, and doing a reverse DNS to the domain, which I think is causing the issue.

`sudo route` on the client:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use 
Iface
default         10.10.0.1       0.0.0.0         UG    50     0        0 
tun0
default         192.168.2.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 
enxb827ebd854fa
default         192.168.2.1     0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 
wlan0
10.10.0.0       10.10.0.1       255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 
tun0
10.10.0.0       *               255.255.255.0   U     50     0        0 
tun0
gateblogs.com   192.168.2.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   100    0        0 
enxb827ebd854fa
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 
tun0
192.168.2.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 
enxb827ebd854fa
192.168.2.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 
wlan0
```

Comment: Please tell us a little more about your network - particularly what IPs are in use for what interfaces. It almost seems to me like a routing issue - what happens if you use "-i any" on the tcpdump? Does traffic exit another interface?  Also, are there iptables rules blocking it?

Comment: I can’t check now, but it showed the requests coming from the external IP instead of 10.10.0.1 like I think it should.

Comment: Are you sure the tunnel is actually up? What, if any routes are shown for it in your routing table?

Comment: The tunnel is up because the ping requests of `tcpdump` are sent to 10.10.0.2,and are being received on the `tun` interface

Comment: I misunderstood your previous comment. It sounds like OpenVPN is not adjusting the routing table correctly so packets are sent back out the wrong interface (but it could be a firewall as well)

Answer (score -1):

If you can't but clients outside of your network can, have you checked to make sure you are part of that VPN network?

1. Are you routing correctly?
2. Have you checked firewall is not filtering TAN/TUN?
3. Are you forwarding correctly?
4. Did you route to your default gateway?